# Why my page is refresed every time I click a empty link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link like this:

```
<a hreflang="15" class="comment-show-link" href="">View/hide comments</a>
```

And then have this code to show/hide the content:

```
$('.comment-show-link').click(function(e) {
  $('#comment-show-'+$(this).attr("hreflang")).slideToggle('slow');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But when I click the link the page is sended and the div "#comment-show-" isn't showed, why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want to use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `stopPropagration`.

Comment: That's what empty `href` values do... if you click the link, it will reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<a data-hreflang="15" class="comment-show-link" href="#">View/hide comments</a>
```

-

```
$('.comment-show-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#comment-show-'+$(this).data("hreflang")).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

or to prevent both the default action and bubbling, do

```
$('.comment-show-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#comment-show-'+$(this).data("hreflang")).slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all of yours the e.preventDefault() was the answer it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 7):

You don't want [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) (which stops the event bubbling), you want [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (which prevents the default action of the event — in this case, following the link). Or just return `false` from your event handler function (which [does both](http://api.jquery.com/on/) *[on the link, scroll down to the paragraph starting with "Returning false..."]*).

Comment: FWIW: `stopPropagation` merely keeps the event from bubbling up in the DOM. It doesn't stop any action on the immediate element. Conversely, `preventDefault` will stop the action on the immediate element from taking place but *will* allow the event to bubble up the DOM, so any parent elements watching for clicks will still activate.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Was that for the OP, or for me? (If for the OP, always feel free to edit answers to improve them; that's what SO is all about!) :-)

Comment: It was for OP. I saw a teachable moment ;). Usually for something like that I'll just go for a comment.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Gotcha. :-) Inspired me to improve the answer, anyway. Best,

Answer (score 1):

Just pass to `href` attribute `javascript:;` value

```
<a hreflang="15" class="comment-show-link" href="javascript:;">View/hide comments</a>
```

Comment: To explain: This is saying "execute javascript in the href value", but then there is no Javascript-- just an empty line, which causes no changes.

Comment: Better: Use a proper href value and use `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

That is the behavior of the anchor tag. I think you want e.PreventDefault to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the href, it's useless (and of course it would be better to use a simple span).

If you added it to change the cursor, use css instead (cursor:pointer).

Comment: If you remove it entirely, the `a` will no longer be a tab stop by default (and won't be listed in lists of links, and various other side-effects). Of course, you can restore the tab behavior with `tabindex`...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preventDefault()`;

```
$('.comment-show-link').click(function(e) {
  $('#comment-show-'+$(this).attr("hreflang")).slideToggle('slow');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a link.

You're not linking to anything so it doesn't make sense to mark up your content as being a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.comment-show-link').click(function(e) {
  $('#comment-show-'+$(this).attr("hreflang")).slideToggle('slow');
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the href attribute to **href="javascript:void(0);"**

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/septerr/taCvq/